# Query for joining 2 tables (using LIKE and prepared statements)

Tags: php, mysql

Hy dear friends ! I want to thank you all for being so helpful and understanding with noobs like me. This is my second question here so please have mercy.

I want to join 2 tables (AUTHORS and BOOKS) so that AUTHOR_REF from Table 2 will be the complete name of the author from Table 1 (not the AUTHOR_REF). 
(There is a Foreign key constraint relationship between authors.id and books.author_ref

The 2 TABLES are:

```
    **ID     LAST NAME     FIRST NAME**
      1      Palahniuk     Chuck
      2      Faulkner      William 
      3      Beckett       Samuel

    **ID     TITLE               AUTHOR_REF**
      1      Fight Club              1
      2      Absalom, Absalom!!      2
      3      Choke                   1
      4      Waiting for Godot       3
```

**CASE/QUESTION:**
User searches for a certain book on the site. I use prepared statements to prepare the query:

```
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT title, autor_ref FROM books WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')" );
```

I know I should use some JOIN with a WHERE condition similar to: 'authors.last_name=books.author_ref' but I already have a WHERE condition from the first SELECT. How can I accomplish my goal ?

I'm really confused. Is my database badly designed ?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated. 
Regards

Answer (score 2):

No, you actually are on the right track, and your database is correctly designed.  The `JOIN` will have its own `ON` condition which does not belong in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
  title, 
  `FIRST NAME`,
  `LAST NAME`
FROM
  books
  /* Join brings over the author name */
  JOIN authors ON books.AUTHOR_REF = authors.ID
/* WHERE clause does not change */
WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```

If you have any books which *don't* have a known author (`AUTHOR_REF IS NULL`), use a `LEFT JOIN` instead so the book title is still returned with `NULL`s for the author name.

```
SELECT
  title, 
  `FIRST NAME`,
  `LAST NAME`
FROM
  books
  /* Left join ensures a row returned for the book even if it has no author */
  LEFT JOIN authors ON books.AUTHOR_REF = authors.ID
WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```

Comment: Yey, it works so well. Thanks so much for your help Micheal.Really helpful. You saved me :)

Answer (score 1):

i would structure the database a bit diferent on this one...

```
AUTHORID     LAST NAME     FIRST NAME
  1          Palahniuk     Chuck
  2          Faulkner      William 
  3          Beckett       Samuel

BOOKID     TITLE               AUTHORID
  1        Fight Club              1
  2        Absalom, Absalom!!      2
  3        Choke                   1
  4        Waiting for Godot       3
```

then join them by using:

```
SELECT title, `FIRST NAME`,`LAST NAME`
FROM books
LEFT JOIN author USING (AUTHORID) 
WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT a.*, b.autor_ref FROM authors as a, books as b WHERE b.author_ref = a.id AND b.title LIKE '%$search%'" );
```

After fetching this you can display full authors name and much much more (like more movies of that author).